# how to replace my local copy with Remote copy？

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse, assembla

I am using Eclipse+subclipse which host my code in assembla. The remote copy(save in assembla) is the latest version. My local copy is not up-to-date. I want to replace my local copy(actually its just one .jsp file) with the remote file in assembla. Which action i should take? Merge? Update? Check in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options, but perhaps just the easiest is to move your current local repository to a different directory and check out a new repository.  No reason to mess with merging if you do not care about your local repository.